# Position div immediately to the right of text input-field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to position a div immediately to the right of text being typed in a text input-field. To me, this seems as simple as taking the length of the input's val and positioning the div to that value. However, what is happening is that it is only right after the text when there is 1 character in the input-field. As more and more are typed, the offset becomes larger and larger.

What i'm trying to create is a suggestion box that will complete a word that is being typed.

How can I position this so that on each keyup it is to the right and right next to the input's value?

Here is a js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ugkzdjsy/

And here is how I'm trying to position it on keyup:

```
$('input').on('keyup', function(){
    $('#suggestion').css('left', $(this).val().length+'rem');
});

No matter what units I try, px, em, rem, I get similar results.
```

Comment: It's also not right after the text with 1 character, it's just not got enough of a 'sizing bug' at that point to notice. You're naively using `rem` as a size unit, while that doesn't reflect the actual width of the characters typed, just a standardized width based on the current font. Your whole current approach cannot work, sorry, and is a good example of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should ask a new question about how to solve your problem, rather than ask help with an attempted (and impossible) solution.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to calculate the width of the text and then set the `left` property.

Here's a JavaScript function that will do it.

This function creates a `span` tag gives it the same property as the `input` tag, appends the `input` text to the `span`, then appends the `span` tag to the DOM and get the `width` using `.offsetWidth`.

```js
$('input').on('keyup', function() {
  $('#suggestion').css('left', width($(this).val()) + 1 + 'px');
});

function width(text) {
  var s = document.createElement('span');
  var t = document.createTextNode(text)
  s.appendChild(t);
  s.id = 'length';
  s.style.fontSize = '1.2rem';
  s.style.visibily = 'hidden';
  s.style.opacity = '0';
  var m = document.getElementById('suggestion');
  for (i = 0; i < m.children.length; i++) {
    if (m.children[i].id == 'length') {
      m.removeChild(m.children[i]);
    }
  }
  m.appendChild(s);
  return (s.offsetWidth * 0.935 > document.getElementById('inpt').offsetWidth) ? document.getElementById('inpt').offsetWidth : s.offsetWidth * 0.935;
};
```

```css
html,
body {
  font-size: 16px;
}
input {
  height: 2.618rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
#suggestion {
  height: 1.5rem;
  width: 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
  background: #66bb6a;
  color: #000000;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-family: 'Myriad Pro', 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  top: -35px;
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inpt" type="text" val="leonardo" />
<div id="suggestion"></div>
```

Comment: Now, it covers up some of the letters. Sometimes the last one, sometimes more. Run the code snippet here or check here: http://jsfiddle.net/ugkzdjsy/3/ and type mn,,nmnmsdl,.fn, or something that long and you'll see that it is not exactly to the right, but, now, a little too much to the left.